# How to access inner TreeViewItem nodes without expanding the parent node

Tags: wpf, silverlight, treeview, visual-tree

I have a WPF TreeView that is bound to a collection of custom objects - each of which has an IsExpanded property to expand the container TreeViewItem. I want to be able to programmatically access each TreeViewItem's control contents without expanding the parent TreeViewItem in the visual tree. However, when I attempt to access said items without expanding their parent it seems as if they have not been added to the visual tree yet. Does anyone know a work around for this?